# How to animate a QPixmap inside another QPixmap with QPropertyanimation

Tags: c++, qt, animation

To animate a QPixmap I used this code :

```
QLabel  *label  = new QLabel(this);
QPixmap image = QPixmap("C://save.png");
image = image.scaledToHeight(40,Qt::SmoothTransformation );
label->setPixmap(image);
//...
//...
QPropertyAnimation* animation = new QPropertyAnimation(label, "geometry");
animation->setDuration(10000);
animation->setStartValue(QRect(0, 0, 40, 40));
animation->setEndValue(QRect(250, 250,40, 40));
animation->start();
```

So on this example I animated a QLabel with a QPixmap inside, but that's not what I want to do now, I want to animate a QPixmap inside another QPixmap, because I want to be able to export the QPixmap (containing all the animated QPixmaps) into a QImage (So I want to do a screenshot).

Is it possible to do it with QPropertyAnimation? If not I'll code my own animation class.

Comment: Not sure what you want exactly. If you want to do that with widgets, have a look at [`QWidget::grab()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grab). Of course, the resulting pixmap can be converted to an image. But if you want to avoid widgets altogether, you can draw a pixmap onto a pixmap using `QPainter`. But for animating that, you can't use `QPropertyAnimation`.

Comment: Thank you very much, QWidget::grab() is exactly what I searched :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at QVariantAnimation. Here you can animate a QRect or a QPoint and other types. You can use those animated variants in your drawing function to lets say influence the position of a pixmap to draw.